# Does ember only respect single sectioned controller names with the 'needs' property

Tags: debugging, ember.js

I have a problem with a Controller not inheriting context from another via needs property. The problem only presents itself when the naming convention of the Routes/Controllers consists of more than a single word.

For example if I have a Resource: `banks` and a Controller: `BanksController` then I can successfully inject its context into another Controller via `controllers.banks.content` with `needs: ['banks']`

*However*

If I have a Resource: `bank-accounts` and a Controller `BankAccountsController`; The context of the injected controller is always empty. So for example `controllers.bankAccounts.content` via `needs: ['bankAccounts']` does ***not*** work, it is always empty from my attempts thus far.

I suspect this may be a bug with how Ember's need feature is internally dealing with naming conventions.

Here are two jsbin's illustrating the issue:

**With single segment variable name** *working example*

http://jsbin.com/qogit/2/edit?html,js,output

**With Double segment variable name** *non working example*

http://jsbin.com/liquj/3/edit?html,js,output

**Additional Note:**

Another *issue I'm having with the needs property is that even with the single variable naming convention for the Route and Controller the `accounts` route initially will show **empty** *if* you visit that resource before the needed Controller's `banks` Route

So apparently only in the use case of a nested route is the needs property actually working?

Appreciate any insights on this..

Comment: AFAIK route level controllers are only created when we visit them. So if we need something in a child controller we may need to put the data in the parent controller. In your case that will be the application controller. You can use needs as needs: ['bank-accounts']. Here is the demo http://jsbin.com/cowoc/1/edit

Comment: I see your solution solves the first part, however the all accounts still shows empty if you visit the route which needs the other. So if I click on all accounts initially the context is not there? I must click on bank accounts first before the accounts route can borrow its context.. any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK route level controllers are only created when we visit them. So if we need something in a child controller we may need to put the data in the parent controller. In your case that will be the application controller.

You can use needs as `needs: ['bank-accounts']`. This will solve your first question. [Here is the demo](http://jsbin.com/cowoc/1/edit).

For your second question, I have made the application controller to fetch the model data as the same data is required by the 2 child routes - 'accounts','bank-accounts'. Now both the route controllers will use the application controller content. [Here is the working demo](http://jsbin.com/cowoc/2/edit).

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.BankAccounts;
  }
});

App.BankAccountsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  bankAccounts: Em.computed.alias('controllers.application.content'),
  init: function(){
    console.log(this.get('content'));
  }
});

App.AccountsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['application'],

  bankAccounts: Em.computed.alias('controllers.application.content'),
  init: function(){
    console.log(this.get('controllers.application.content'));
  }
});
```