# Ember controller dependency resolution not working on direct links?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I use dependency resolution between controllers in Ember and it works fine as long as you navigate down the route. But If you directly link to the view which has a controller which has a dependency, it does not work with the following error message:

```
needs [ controller:productsDetailIndex ] but it could not be found
```

The according controller:

```
Pd.ProductsDetailOrderController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: "productsDetailIndex"
});
```

Router:

```
Pd.Router.map(function () {

    this.resource('products', { path: '/products' }, function () {
        this.resource('products.detail', { path: '/:product_id' }, function() {
            this.route('order');
        });

    });
});

Pd.ProductsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.all('product');
    }
});

Pd.ProductsDetailIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.getById('product', params.product_id);
    }
});

Pd.ProductsDetailOrderRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});
```

So, if I go to `/products/3` and click on link which opens `/products/3/oder` it's all good. But If I directly link to `/products/3/order` the above error comes up.

Comment: Some what similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737622/does-ember-only-respect-single-sectioned-controller-names-with-the-needs-prope/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your logic is dependent on a controller that isn't in its path you've got an architectural problem.  In your particular case the resource is in its path, so you should move whatever logic you have in the index controller into the 'productsDetail' controller.

```
Pd.ProductsDetailRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.getById('product', params.product_id);
    }
});

Pd.ProductsDetailIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.modelFor('productDetails');
    }
});
```

Comment: If the productDetailIndex controller is not available, why should the productsIndex controller be available?

Comment: Because the resource is always built.  The index route on each of your resources is just the default route that's hit when you only hit a resource, it still hits the resource itself.

Comment: I tossed an example, additionally your products detail index is spelled wrong, you have `procucts`.